# Elixir's GenServer handle_call, handle_info, handle_cast not being invoked

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I've implemented a simple `Application` -> `DynamicSupervisor` system where the `Application` creates a single `DynamicSupervisor` on startup and then sends a message to it to start some work. The problem is that none of the messages (through GenServer's `cast`, Kernel's `send`) actually get caught. Trying to `GenServer.call()` throws the following error

> no function clause matching in DynamicSupervisor.handle_call/3

which is odd since I have implemented it (to that spec). I'm sure that the `DynamicSupervisor` module gets started and doesn't quit on startup.

Application module code:

```
defmodule Simulacra.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      Simulacra.MainSupervisor
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Simulacra.Supervisor]
    {:ok, pid} = Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
    start_supervisors(Supervisor.which_children(pid))
    {:ok, pid}
  end

  defp start_supervisors([h|_t] = list) when is_list(list) do
    {_, pid, _, _} = h
    start_supervisors(pid)
  end

  defp start_supervisors([]) do
    #noop
    IO.puts "Something"
  end

  defp start_supervisors(pid) do
    GenServer.cast(pid, :start)
    send(pid, :ping)
    GenServer.call(pid, :ping) <-- Throws an error
  end
end
```

Supervisor code:

```
defmodule Simulacra.MainSupervisor do
  @moduledoc false
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link([]) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_noop) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def handle_info(:ping, state) do
    IO.puts "sth"
  end

  def handle_cast(:start, state) do
    # do_something
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_call(:ping, _from, _x) do
    {:reply, "bing", "bong"}
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DynamicSupervisor` is a custom *implementation* of [`GenServer` behaviour](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/c5d5e7f462ff04c7baf13a27eb810fe903979b7d/lib/elixir/lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex#L132).

The only overridable function it has is [`child_spec/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/c5d5e7f462ff04c7baf13a27eb810fe903979b7d/lib/elixir/lib/dynamic_supervisor.ex#L232).

Your `casts` are although effectively ignored. When you cast a message, or send an info, VM simply ignores it when the process can not process it (or even if it does not exist.) `call/3` is synchronous, so the sender expects a reply back, that is why you see it raises.

Try `GenServer.cast pid, :foo`, you’ll receive `:ok` back, because these messages are not promised to be delivered.

Comment: Yeah, I understood why the `call()` was the only thing to throw an error due to its synchronous nature but I had no clue that `DynamicSupervisor` didn't have those overridable functions that `GenServer` has. Thanks

Comment: `GenServer` does not have anything. `GenServer` is [_a behaviour_](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?). When one calls `use GenServer`. it calls a macro `GenServer.__using__/1` under the hood, which, in turn, injects a whole bunch of code, making the default implementations [overridable](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/a914197b521c58113b4ba893e1fb30eec4928cf2/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex#L821). `DynamicSupervisor` implements the behaviour on it’s own, disallowing overriding.